# Address boundary error on dynamic array

Tags: c

I'm just starting with `C` from a interpreted language background, and I'm having problems understanding why this is not working.

I have a `Dynamic_Array` struct (http://pastebin.com/h4k7Sk3U), and a `Task` struct (http://pastebin.com/evs4TEQA).

When creating a `Dynamic_Array` instance with an initial size I get:

```
“./ctask ” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I tracked the error with `gdb`, who shows that its originated on `dynamic_array.h:16`:

```
Dynamic_Array *dynamic_array_create(size_t initialSize) {
  Dynamic_Array *a;
  a->array = (Task *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(Task));   // line 16
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
  return a;
}
```

What am I doing wrong there? I'm multiplying the initial size with the size of the `Task` struct, which is supposed to be enough memory for them.

Comment: In line 15, you only said "I have a pointer named `a`", you did not actually create any object for it to point to. Lines 15-16 are similar to doing `var a; a.foo = ...;` in JavaScript. (Also, you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never allocated `a` itself, before you started creating its members.

Until you initialize it, `a` is pointing to some random memory location that you shouldn't be touching.

```
Dynamic_Array *dynamic_array_create(size_t initialSize) {
  Dynamic_Array *a = malloc(sizeof(Dynamic_Array));  // create 'a' first

  a->array = (Task *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(Task));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
  return a;
}
```